# Gas line in stove

Tags: gas-burner

This is picture of my gas stove. There are two gas  lines you can see, each controlled by knob and going to burner. Where I circled, there is a small slit , I am wondering what is that for ? Why wouldn't gas leak from there and catch flame ?[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The gas is mixed with air before going to the burner, the slit allows air to enter.

The gas does not leak from there becase there is a jet of gas causing a wind current blowing down the tube to the burner.

Comment: Otherwise known as a venturi ; the flowing gas sucks in air. Without it the burner flame would be yellow/ orange and put soot on pans.

Comment: @user2716454, think of a garden hose and a puddle ... if you spray water into a puddle at an angle, the water stream will drag the water in the puddle and empty the puddle ... the gas stream is like a water stream from the garden hose, it drags the surrounding air along